# Django Nginx Gunicorn - Media Files Not Showing (DigitalOcean Deployment)

Tags: django, nginx, media, gunicorn

I have deployed a Django project on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx and Gunicorn. I have gotten everything, including the static files but my media files will not serve properly.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

models.py

```
resume_upload = models.FileField(blank=False, upload_to='resumes', null=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf']), validate_file_size])
```

What I have listed in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ is

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name website.com www.website.com ;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/syed/btawebsite;
}

location = /media/ {
    root /home/syed/btawebsite;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/syed/myproject.sock;
}
```

}

I would like go on the admin, click on the uploaded file and be able to view the file in the browser. Anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this? I have verified through using the terminal and looking through the directories that the files are in fact adding to ~btawebsite/media/resumes but I am unable to view them when I click the admin url.

When I click on that url I get an error:

Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.

**Update:**

I have changed settings.py to

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

And nginx settings to

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/syed/btawebsite/static/;
}

location = /media/ {
    alias /home/syed/btawebsite/media/;
}
```

Static is still working, however, media is not.

Comment: Since the location of your media should be /home/syed/btawebsit according to your nginx settings, that should also be your `MEDIA_ROOT`. Note that you make a mistake by setting the same location for static and media, you'll get files in the same directory which you don't want. You probably want to have /home/syed/btawebsit/static/ and /home/syed/btawebsit/media/ instead.

Comment: I have made those changes and it is still not working.

Comment: I don't know based on your description how /home/syed/btawebsit/media/ relates to your BASE_DIR. If your settings are correct, /home/syed/btawebsit is your BASE_DIR, i.e manage.py is next to /media and /static. If that's not the case, then you need to define MEDIA_ROOT differently so that it points to /home/syed/btawebsit/media/ or change your nginx path to match the path of your MEDIA_ROOT. Best way to check: upload a file, check the path to the file on your system using ssh. Is it located at /home/syed/btawebsit/media/filename.jpg?

Comment: So I've uploaded a file and it is located in /home/syed/btawebsite/media/resumes/example.pdf so the files are getting uploaded where I want them to be, however, I can't access it through the browser.

Comment: What's the url you see in the browser to that same file? (in the source)

Comment: http://www.website.com/media/resumes/example.pdf

Comment: sorry I see you're using `root` not `alias` in nginx. The original settings you have in your question should be the correct ones

Comment: I have tried with both, root and alias but neither work, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190517/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-express-v2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For nginx configuration, the "=" sign after location means this is the exact location match. So change your settings to

```
location /media/ {
    root /home/syed/btawebsite;
}
```

and same for `/static/`. It's correct for the favicon. For more about the nginx location directive, check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms).